# Multiple timers in a loop

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, timer

I have an array of characters, eg.

```
["A","E","I","O","U","Y"]
```

I should loop this array and, for every character, start a timer. That is: if the current letter is A, A must be printed and last 2 seconds. After A has been printed, we need to print "E" and it should last 3 seconds, "I" one second, "O" four seconds, etc.

I think I should create a new timer for every character, this way:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeInterval, target: self, selector: 
#selector(printCharacter), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

but I can't do it inside the loop.

I hoped there was a way to build an array of timers and then fire them sequentially, but this is not possible. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using recursion and `DispatchQueue` only. If you are not familiar with recursion a simple way to understand it's by [googling it](https://www.google.nl/search?q=recursion)

A sample code if print duration isn't linear would look like following :

```
var currentIndex = 0
let charactersArray = ["A","B","C","D"]
let durations : [TimeInterval] = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]

func printCharacter(){

    guard currentIndex < charactersArray.count else { return }

    print(charactersArray[currentIndex])

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + durations[currentIndex], execute: {

        currentIndex = currentIndex + 1

        printCharacter()
    })
}

printCharacter()
```

where durations array represent time shown for each character

Comment: I'm familiar with recursion and queues too   :-)   Thanks, your solution is way better than the last one I tried

Comment: Just a little typo in your code (duration should be durations with final s). And TimeInterval should be Double (am I right?)

Comment: @3000 As for the missing s you are completely right. TimeInterval is typealias of Double and it is used to make code more readable when dealing with timings

Comment: Okok, I had to imagine the typealias, sorry   ;-)